# Смена значений select с помощью jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Вывожу форму при помощи php:

```
<td><input type='text' name='user[3][user_name]' value='Румянцев А.А.' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user[3][name_otdel]' value='Отдел Веб-технологий' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
            <td>
            <select name='user[3][pravo]' class='sel1'>

               <option value='0' selected="selected">Нет</option>
            <option value='1'>Да</option>

                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
             <select name='user[3][pravo2]' class='sel2'>
                <option value='0'selected="selected">Нет</option>
                <option value='1'>Да</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
             <select name='user[3][pravo3]' class='sel3'>
                <option value='0';>Нет</option>
                <option value='1'selected="selected">Да</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='user[2][user_name]' value='Зайцев С.Г.' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user[2][name_otdel]' value='' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
            <td>
            <select name='user[2][pravo]' class='sel1'>

               <option value='0' >Нет</option>
            <option value='1'selected="selected">Да</option>

                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
             <select name='user[2][pravo2]' class='sel2'>
                <option value='0'selected="selected">Нет</option>
                <option value='1'>Да</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
             <select name='user[2][pravo3]' class='sel3'>
                <option value='0'selected="selected";>Нет</option>
                <option value='1'>Да</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

То есть у каждой запись есть три `select'a`, но все это находится на одной форме. Нужно чтобы при выборе в одном из `select` "да" в последующих двух менялись значения на нет. Пробовал написать обработчик `onChange` но он меняет `select` у всех записей.

Comment: Ну и для чего радиобаттоны существуют? Хотя тут вообще одним select'ом можно обойтись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего проще. Вешаете обработку события, где выбираете все соседние элементы относительно строки и сбрасываете у них значение:

```js
$(function(){ // on ready document
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not($(this)).val(0);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="user[3][pravo]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
              <select name="user[3][pravo2]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
              <select name="user[3][pravo3]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="user[2][pravo]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
              <select name="user[2][pravo2]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
              <select name="user[2][pravo3]">
                <option value="1">да</option>
                <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все работает. Надо бы разобраться более подробно с JS и JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#myform select').on('change', function() {
  $('#myform select').not($(this)).val(0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="">
  <select name="s1" id="">
    <option value="1">да</option>
    <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
  </select>
  <select name="s2" id="">
    <option value="1">да</option>
    <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
  </select>
  <select name="s3" id="">
    <option value="1">да</option>
    <option value="0" selected>нет</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но вот у меня получается выводится несколько записей с тремя select в одной форме. Данный обработчик меняет все select. То есть у меня в одной форме (sel1,sel2,sel3)*количество записей

Comment: Добавь select'ам, которые должны меняться в пределах данной формы    , какой-нибудь класс, селектор станет таким $('#myform select.my_class')